# Is this vbs code safe?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I do not understand vbs commands. Can someone explain these, and tell me if it is safe to download to my friends computer? This is the code:

```
cls
:A
color 0a
cls
@echo off
echo Wscript.Sleep
echo Wscript.Sleep 5000>C:sleep5000.vbs
echo Wscript.Sleep 3000>C:sleep3000.vbs


echo Wscript.Sleep 4000>C:sleep4000.vbs
echo Wscript.Sleep 2000>C:sleep2000.vbs
cd %systemroot%System32
dir
cls
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep3000.vbs
echo Deleting Critical System Files…
echo del .
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep3000.vbs
echo Deletion Successful!
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
echo:
echo:
echo:
echo Deleting Root Partition…
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
echo del %SYSTEMROOT%
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep4000.vbs
echo Deletion Successful!
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
echo:
echo:
echo:
echo Creating Directory h4x…
cd C:Documents and SettingsAll UsersStart MenuPrograms
mkdir h4x
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep3000.vbs
echo Directory Creation Successful!
echo:
echo:
echo:
echo Execution Attempt 1…
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep3000.vbs
echo cd C:Documents and SettingsAll UsersStart MenuProgramsStartuph4x
echo start hax.exe
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep3000.vbs
echo Virus Executed!
echo:
echo:
echo:
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
echo Disabling Windows Firewall…
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
echo Killing all processes…
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
echo Allowing virus to boot from startup…
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
echo:
echo:
echo Virus has been executed successfully!
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
echo:
echo Have fun!
start /w wscript.exe C:sleep2000.vbs
pause
shutdown -s -t 10 -c “Your computer has committed suicide. Have a nice          day.”
```

Comment: if you don't know what it is, why are you even considering downloading it?

Comment: i found it on a website listed as a prank but i wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is not `vbs`, it is pure batch that attempts to echo command to `.vbs` files and attempts to execute `.vbs` scripts as well as system commands  .

It is purely a Virus hoax / prank script someone, with no clue, created.

So is it safe? Looking at a the poorly written batch, it won't even execute half the commands, let alone cause harm, however the pure thought that you are willing to download scripts from the internet with **any** relation to Virus' makes everything you do unsafe.

I am not going to get into the actual script itself, because it has way to many issues. I suggest you follow some simple documentation on your Windows PC by performing simple commands and help switches, here are some clues:

```
help
cmd /?
start /?
cscript.exe /?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points I noticed:

- It shuts down the computer after the script ends(this can be aborted)
- There are also some possible syntax errors and poorly written script.

  - `echo Wscript.Sleep 4000>C:sleep4000.vbs` is poorly written
  - `start /w wscript.exe C:sleep3000.vbs` - sleep3000.vbs was not created
  - `C:filename` is an incorrect way to refer to a file
  - `start /w wscript.exe` is not the best way to start a VBS script.

---

Overall, all messages are fake. Nevertheless, I do not recommend running this file, as there may be malware hidden in alternate streams.